# I got undefined while checking error kind in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When I enter valid id after /user/ as 'http://localhost:5000/api/profile/user/5ee9fbe0e82023146c8a5230', it returns result as expected. But I need to check error kind if error occurs when user give invalid id. So I intentionally entered invalid id as 'http://localhost:5000/api/profile/user/5ee9fbe0e82023146c8a52304'. Now It throws the error as

```
MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5ee9fbe0e82023146c8a52304" at path "user" for model "profile"
    at new CastError (D:\Programming\MERN\devConnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:29:11)
    at model.Query.exec (D:\Programming\MERN\devConnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4341:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (D:\Programming\MERN\devConnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4433:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"5ee9fbe0e82023146c8a52304"',
  kind: undefined,
  value: '5ee9fbe0e82023146c8a52304',
  path: 'user',
  reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
      at new ObjectID (D:\Programming\MERN\devConnector\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
      at castObjectId (D:\Programming\MERN\devConnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast 
}
```

Now I want to check error.kind but there is undefined. What's wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#error_Error-ValidatorError) the `kind`-property is only populated for `ValidatorError`s.

In your case you get an error of type `CastError` which does not have `kind` listed in its properties: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-CastError

So this seems like working as intended.