# Having trouble with passport authentication and redirects

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, dashboard

I tried some every possible thing but definitely, there is something I cannot recognize

### index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');

// Home Page
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});

//DashBoard
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard');
})

module.exports = router;
```

### auth.js

```
module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Please login first');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
}
```

### users.js

```
enter code here
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const passport = require('passport');

// Login Page
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
})

//Register Page
router.get('/register', async(req, res) => {
    res.render('register');
})

// Register Handle
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    let errors = [];

    // Check required fields
    if (!username && !password) {
        errors.push({ msg: "Please fill all fields" })
    }

    // Check password length
    if (password.length < 6 && password > 0) {
        errors.push({ msg: "Password should be atleat 6 characters"   
    })
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        res.render('register', {
            errors,
            username,
            password
        }, console.log(errors));
    } else {
        // Validation passed
        User.findOne({ username: username })
            .then(async user => {
                if (user) {
                    //User exists
                    errors.push({ msg: "username has already taken" 
                       });
                    res.render('register', {
                        errors,
                        username,
                        password
                    });
                } else {

                    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                    const hashedPassword = await 
                                 bcrypt.hash(password, salt);


                    const newUser = new User({
                        username: username,
                        password: hashedPassword,
                    });
                    newUser.save()
                        .then(user => {
                            // res.status(201).json(user);
                            req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now 
                                                      registered')
                            res.redirect('/users/login');
                        })
                        .catch(err => console.log(err));
                }
                        })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
      }
});

   // Login Handle
router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true
    })
);

// Logout Handle
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');
    res.redirect('/users/login');
})


module.exports = router;
```

So these are some codes working, not giving any kind of error except that after logging in it is not rendering me to dashboard while removing
"ensureAuthenticated" from the router.get('/dashboard') it works, but when it works then the logout handle does not work.

Comment: We really need you to add details otherwise we are not able to answer your question. What does your code look like, what is the code trying to do, where is this `messageFormat: undefined, stringValue: '"{ username: 'admin', password: '123455' }"', kind: 'string', value: { username: 'admin', password: '123455' }, path: 'username', reason: null }` coming from?

Comment: I am sending a signup form by post method and in that field I have given only username and password field, when I'm trying to post the method on console it gives me this instead of
Username: admin
Password: 123455

Comment: Thank you that was very useful information. But seeing some example code would also be extremely useful and would've probably saved me a solid 10 minutes. As far as I'm aware, it seems to be something related with `mongoose` or `mongodb`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434168/i-got-undefined-while-checking-error-kind-in-mongodb

Comment: @MichaelHoobler, could you please help me in this

Comment: @MichaelHoobler, this is the new one, I edited the question

Comment: @MichaelHoobler, the earlier one problem we were discussing it got resolved

Comment: Thank you for adding your code and adding those tags, but I did not know you were using `passport` and I can not help you because I am unfamiliar with passport. You should maybe try making a NEW question (it is hard to find old questions like this). The title should be something like "Having trouble with passport authentication and redirects". Sorry I can't help, and good luck.

Comment: @MichaelHoobler no issue, thank you for your precious time. Could you please share it with someone who can help